# How to create pdf with command line using MiKTeX?

Tags: pdf, compiling, windows

I downloaded and installed MikTeX on my machine (Windows 7), then when I run the command:

```
latex ex.tex
```

the outputs were:

1. ex.aux
2. ex.dvi
3. ex.log

So my question is, what option could I use to produce `ex.pdf`? Any suggestion?

Comment: To produce PDF output, you have 2 choices: using `pdflatex` only or using `latex` followed by `dvips` followed by `ps2pdf`. The former `pdflatex` allows you to import PDF, JPG, and PNG images. The latter `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` allows you to import EPS images and PSTricks code. It is worth using an editor to write your input file .tex. There are many editors for Windows, such as TeXnicCenter, TeXStudio (formerly named as TeXMakerX), etc.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Run `pdflatex ex.tex` to produce a pdf file from the tex file directly. Alternatively, after obtaining the dvi file from `latex ex.tex`, run `dvips -P pdf ex.dvi` followed by `ps2pdf ex.ps` to produce a ps file and then a pdf file, or `dvipdfm ex.dvi` to produce a pdf file.

It is much easier to do these using a LaTeX editor. You may also want to consider using automated processes provided by say `latexmk` which runs various executables the required number of times (sometimes one run is not sufficient) to give the right final output. Also note that some packages cannot work with some methods. For example, `pstricks` does not work with `pdflatex` or `dvipdfm`.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I've just figured it out ^_^! Simple enough: "pdf" prefix.

Comment: `texify` is preferred to `latexmk` in MiKTeX. And always use `dvipdfmx` instead of `dvipdfm` if possible. And there are `xelatex` and `lualatex` to produce PDF output with better Unicode support and many other features.

Comment: @LeoLiu: Why is `texify` better for MiKTeX than `latexmk`? Perhaps you can share your experiences in [texify or latexmk?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38373)